# Uploading file with PHP to imageshack using cURL

Tags: php, file, curl, upload, imageshack

I am trying to upload a file to imageshack using following script:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://post.imageshack.us/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$post = array(
    'fileupload'=> '@../../resources/images/cancel.png',
    'optsize' => 'resample',
    'rembar' => '1'
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
```

However, I get following error from imageshack:

`Wrong file type detected for file cancel.png:application/octet-stream`.

Why is that, and how can it be fixed? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
It does work when I use JPGs or GIFs (even animated ones, although Imageshack then de-animates them, I think by only using the first frame), but not with PNGs.

**EDIT 2:**
I found out how to fix it. As stated earlier, it does only accept JPGs and GIFs. So I take the location of the image I need to upload, copy it to a temporary location *with the ending `.jpg`*, upload the file, and then, upon completion, I remove the file from the temporary location.

Answer (score 2):

Set the Content-type to the type of the file.

According to the manual, it must be an array or object. So here

```
$arr = array('Content-type: text/plain') ;
curl_setopt ( $ch , CURL_HTTPHEADER , $arr );
```

Comment: Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: You must pass either an object or an array with the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, CURLOPT_QUOTE, CURLOPT_HTTP200ALIASES and CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE arguments in …

Comment: So I tried that way: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type' => 'image/png'));` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @arik-so What was the response? You should check whether your png is valid.

Comment: The response was the same as before. I also treid using binary transfer, which still did not work. However, when I tried using another image, it did work, but only the first time.